# If $N$ and $H$ are normal subgroups of $G$, then $N\cap H$ is also normal in $G$ and $G/(N\cap H)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $(G/N)\times(G/H)$?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism, quotient-group

I've already shown that $N\cap H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, so I just need to determine an isomorphism.

My problem is that I'm not entirely sure I understand what $(G/N)\times(G/H)$ looks like. I know that $G/N$ is the collection of left cosets of $N$ in $G$ and similarly $G/H$ is the collection of left cosets of $H$ in $G$. So what is $(G/N)\times(G/N)$ the collection of exactly?

In constructing an isomorphism I need to define bijective mapping $f:G/(N\cap H) \to (G/N)\times(G/H)$ which also preserves the operation of $G/(N\cap H)$. I feel I need to understand the structure of the $(G/N)\times(G/H)$ in order to do this.

Comment: The direct product of two groups is a cartesian product (of sets) where the operation is taken component-wise: $(a, b) (c, d) = (ac, bd)$

Comment: Okay, I thought that might be the direction so $(G/N)\times(G/H)$ is the set {$(aN,aH) | a \in G$}. So how would one construct an mapping in this case?

Comment: Consider the map $aN \cap H \to (aN, aH)$

Comment: Why are you trying to prove something that isn't true? For example it is obviously wrong when $H$ and $N$ are both trivial.

Comment: Perhaps you missed out the assumption that $NH=G$?

Comment: I wondered that myself, so I looked at the question again and realized I copied the statement incorrectly. It is fixed now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well to see that $N\cap H$ is normal (it is obviously a subgroup), let $g\in G$ and $s\in N\cap H$. Since $s\in N$ and $N$ is normal, $gsg^{-1}\in N$. Since $s\in H$ and $H$ is normal, $gsg^{-1}\in H$. Thus $gsg^{-1}\in H\cap N$. This is precisely the definition of a normal subgroup.

Define $\phi:G\to G/H\times G/N$ by $g\mapsto (gH, gN)$. This map is a well-defined group homomorphism. It is not true that $\phi$ is surjective in general. The kernel of this map is the set of $s\in G$ such that $sH=H$ and $sN=N$, which is precisely the set $H\cap N$, i.e. $\ker(\phi)=H\cap N$ (since kernels of group homomorphisms are always normal subgroups, this is another proof that $H\cap N$ is normal).

Let's see why this map is not necessarily surjective. Simply take an abelian group, say $G=\mathbb{Z}$ so every subgroup is normal and then take $H=\{0\}$, the trivial subgroup and $N=2\mathbb{Z}$. Then $\phi$ is the homomorphism
$$\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}_2$$
defined by $n\mapsto(n,[n]_2)$. In particular, the element $(2,[1])$ of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ does not lie in the range of $\phi$.

Let's also see why $\frac{G}{H\cap N}$ is not isomorphic to $\frac{G}{H}\times\frac{G}{N}$ in general. In the same example, if that were true we would have that $\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}_2$. This is obviously false (why?).

Comment: So the proof of isomorphism boils down to defining $ker \phi$ and using the first isomorphism theorem? To your other point, shouldn't every isomorphism be a bijection and therefore be required to be surjective?

Comment: @MrStormy83 The first isomorphism theorem says that if $\phi:G\to H$ is a group homomorphism, then $G/\ker(\phi)\cong\phi(G)\leq H$. So $G/H\cap N$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $G/H\times G/N$, but not to the entire direct product, as we have given examples of that phenomenon.

Comment: It turns out I rewrote the questions incorrectly. I forgot to include the phrase "to a subgroup of." It is fixed!

Comment: @MrStormy83 Oh, I see. I hope my answer helps you understand what's going on

Comment: Yes that definitely helps!